# Am I using Promise.all() incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, promise, sequelize.js

[Code Here](https://github.com/fleshborne/rma-inventory)

Im trying to loop through the iterations of a returned response to accurately depict information as needed.

Currently, CaseContactName and CaseSiteName come in from a different API call, then the data is appended onto a chart, however in it's current state, the responses aren't being synced with what's related to the table data as all these values are tied through model relation.

I want the contact name and the site name to append properly, I've tried 3 different loop methods and its either appended the first name/contact or not at all. It's irritable data, and I was suggested to use the Promise.All function as it's used in cases of irritations yet I feel as though I'm lost here.

***The code is as follows***

```
       const callRmaCases = async () => {
        //    $tbody.empty(); 
             axios.get('/api/Case').then((response) => {
                for(let i = 0; response.data.length > 0; i++){
                    const caseContactName = Promise.resolve(response.data[i].Contact.name);
                    const caseSiteName = Promise.resolve(response.data[i].Site.siteName);
                     console.log(response);
                     console.log(caseContactName, caseSiteName)
                     
                     Promise.all([caseContactName,caseSiteName]).then((values) => {
                        console.log(values);
                        callRmaInvent([caseContactName,caseSiteName])  
                     });
                };
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
            
            };

        const callRmaInvent = async (caseContactName, caseSiteName) => {

        await(caseSiteName, caseContactName);
     axios.get('/api/caseDetail').then((items) => {
        $tbody.empty();
        console.log(items);
        console.log('inventory will go here');
       items.data.forEach((item) => {
            const id = item.id;
            // Table data
            const caseName = item.Case.caseName;
            const caseSite =  caseSiteName;
            const caseContact =  caseContactName;
            const itemType = item.Part.partType;
            const serialNumber = item.Part.serialNumber;
            const createdAt = item.createdAt;
            const updatedAt = item.updatedAt;
            const faultReason = item.Fault.reasonForReturn;
            const dispositionAction = item.Disposition.actionTaken;
            const addedToInvent = dateFns.format(createdAt, 'MMM D, YY')
            const updatedInvent = dateFns.format(updatedAt, 'MMM D, YY')

            $tbody.append(`
            <tr>
            <td>${id}</td>
            <td>${caseName}</td>
            <td>${caseSite}</td>
            <td>${caseContact}</td>
            <td>${serialNumber}</td>
            <td>${itemType}</td>         
            <td>${faultReason}</td>
            <td>${dispositionAction}</td>
            <td>${addedToInvent}</td>
            <td>${updatedInvent}</td>
            </tr>`)
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });   
    };
```

You can see that Contact comes up undefined once here, however is correctly shown afterwards, I might just be really confused here and trying to use the wrong method to achieve the results I need.

Console Log shows:

```
{data: Array(2), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}config: {url: "/api/Case", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}data: (2) [{…}, {…}]headers: {content-length: "1474", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", date: "Mon, 26 Jul 2021 19:47:17 GMT", etag: "W/\"5c2-BNGcGEUTd4sqd6BxFY9mWpUJgeU\"", x-powered-by: "Express"}request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
script.js:16 Promise {<fulfilled>: "Blake Thompson"}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: "Blake Thompson" Promise {<fulfilled>: "Disney World"}
script.js:15 {data: Array(2), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}config: {url: "/api/Case", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}data: (2) [{…}, {…}]headers: {content-length: "1474", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", date: "Mon, 26 Jul 2021 19:47:17 GMT", etag: "W/\"5c2-BNGcGEUTd4sqd6BxFY9mWpUJgeU\"", x-powered-by: "Express"}request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
script.js:16 Promise {<fulfilled>: "Eric"}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: "Eric" Promise {<fulfilled>: "Warehouse"}
script.js:34 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Contact' of undefined
    at script.js:13
script.js:19 (2) ["Blake Thompson", "Disney World"]0: "Blake Thompson"1: "Disney World"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
script.js:19 (2) ["Eric", "Warehouse"]
```

[image: Picture of Table]

Comment: avoid using `.then` in async methods.

Comment: You `console.log(values);`, but then you continue passing `[caseContactName,caseSiteName]` to `callRmaInvent()` which are two promises. Don't do that, use `values`.

Comment: `await(caseSiteName, caseContactName);` does not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: "*Am I using Promise.all() incorrectly?*" - yes, absolutely. You should start by not making `caseContactName` and `caseSiteName` promises - there's no good reason to `Promise.resolve` them!

Comment: @Bergi the syntax examples showed the Promise.resolve as a requirement to use Promise.All() which is why they were used in this case. Appreciate the insight.

Comment: @BlakeT Sorry, I did not mean to come across as rude. But it's quite unclear what you were trying to achieve or why you are trying to use `Promise.all`. Evert explains in his answer below how that call, and the `Promise.resolve` calls, don't make sense.

Comment: "*I was suggested to use the Promise.All function*" - who suggested that? "*the syntax examples showed the Promise.resolve as a requirement to use Promise.All()*" - which "syntax examples" are you talking about? Can you link them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you do makes no sense.

```js
const caseContactName = Promise.resolve(response.data[i].Contact.name);
const caseSiteName = Promise.resolve(response.data[i].Site.siteName);
                     
Promise.all([caseContactName,caseSiteName]).then((values) => {
  callRmaInvent(caseContactName, caseSiteName)  
});
```

In this code sample, you pass 2 promises to `Promise.all()`. The then handler will get the *result* of those 2 promises, but then you don't pass the result to `callRmaInvent`, you pass the original promises.

So instead, you'll want this:

```js
const caseContactName = Promise.resolve(response.data[i].Contact.name);
const caseSiteName = Promise.resolve(response.data[i].Site.siteName);
                     
Promise.all([caseContactName,caseSiteName]).then((values) => {
  callRmaInvent(values[0], values[1])  
});
```

However, the use of `Promise.resolve()` was unneeded here, because you already had the data, so this can be further shortened to:

```js
const caseContactName = response.data[i].Contact.name;
const caseSiteName = response.data[i].Site.siteName;
                     
callRmaInvent(caseContactName, caseSiteName)
```

The entire outer method can be simplified to:

```js
const callRmaCases = async () => {
 
  //    $tbody.empty(); 
  const response = await axios.get('/api/Case');
  for(const item of response.data) {
     const caseContactName = item.Contact.name;
     const caseSiteName = item.Site.siteName;

     callRmaInvent(caseContactName, caseSiteName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just noting that even if `caseContactName` and `caseSiteName` were promises, you could do: `callRmaInvent(...await Promise.all([ caseContactName, caseSiteName ]));`

Comment: I got pulled away from my desk so Im seeing this on mobile, I really appreciate the time you put into your response. There was a few examples of syntax when using promise.All and when I asked an earlier thread on a situation I was dealing with I was pointed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
I will get back into this ASAP.

Comment: @Gershy Ill give it a shot, appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

You have overkilled everything I suppose. I have rewritten a simpler version of your code. Some changes may need to be done based on response from server.

```
const callRmaCases = async () => {
try {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/Case')
    // assuming you are getting a json object
    const responseData = await response.json()
    responseData.forEach(innerObject => {
        callRmaInvent(innerObject.Contact.name, innerObject.Site.siteName)  
    })
} catch(error) {
    console.table(error.name, error.type, error.stack)
}  
};

const callRmaInvent = async (caseContactName, caseSiteName) => {
try {
    const items = await axios.get('/api/caseDetail')
    $tbody.empty();
    items.data.forEach((item) => {
            $tbody.append(`
            <tr>
            <td>${item.id}</td>
            <td>${item.Case.caseName}</td>
            <td>${caseSiteName}</td>
            <td>${item.Part.partType}</td>
            <td>${item.Part.serialNumber}</td>
            <td>${item.Part.partType}</td>         
            <td>${item.Fault.reasonForReturn}</td>
            <td>${item.Disposition.actionTaken}</td>
            <td>${dateFns.format(createdAt, 'MMM D, YY')}</td>
            <td>${dateFns.format(updatedAt, 'MMM D, YY')}</td>
            </tr>`)
    });   
} catch(error) {
    console.table([error.name, error.type, error.stack])
}   
};
```

An unresolved promise can be handled in many way. I love async-await.